# insert or update on table "testrun2attachment" violates foreign key constraint "testrun2attachment_runid_fkey"'

Tags: opentap-proj

I did run a test plan. I did some custom made test steps, a result listener, but no DUT. However I get the following error:

```
16:39:22.181  PGSQL        Resource "opentap @ localhost:5433" opened. [173 ms]
16:39:22.181  Summary      ------ Summary of test plan started 09/10/2020 16:39:22 ------
16:39:22.181  Summary      --------------------------------------------------------------
16:39:22.181  Summary      ----- Test plan completed with verdict Error in 2.33 ms ------
16:39:22.210  PGSQL        Error in OnTestPlanRunCompleted for 'opentap @ localhost:5433': '23503: insert or update on table "testrun2attachment" violates foreign key constraint "testrun2attachment_runid_fkey"'
16:39:22.216  PGSQL        Resource "opentap @ localhost:5433" closed. [1.22 ms]
```

The error message seems cryptic to me.

Comment: Did you only use this PostgreSQL database for OpenTAP and/or did you send any custom commands to it? Did you upgrade the database?
Which version of OpenTAP are you using? Could you provide a printout of the installed packages by running this command: `tap package list --installed`?

Comment: I did only use the database for OpenTAP without any custom commands. I did use the Editor (non CE-version), I think that was the cause of the issue. I did install the Editor CE and the issue went away. I can't run the tap.exe in the installation I used for this issue now, because the tap.exe is gone. I did use OpenTAP 9.9.2 according to the session logs.